# Проблема с sessionStorage с `checkbox` и `radio`

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите понять в чем проблема и как исправить.
Для сохранения данных введенных в форму используется следующий код:

```js
$('[name *= "pdata_ch_"]').each(function () {
 if (sessionStorage.getItem(this.name)) {
 this.value = sessionStorage.getItem(this.name);
}
 switch (this.type) {
   case 'text':
    this.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
     sessionStorage.setItem(this.name, this.value);
     
     console.log("---- text ----");
    });
    break;
   case 'radio':
    this.addEventListener("change", function() {

     sessionStorage.setItem(this.name, this.value);
     console.log("---- radio ----");
     console.log(this.value);
    });
    break;
   case 'select-one':
    this.addEventListener("change", function() {
     sessionStorage.setItem(this.name, this.value);
     
     console.log("---- select-one ----");
    });
    break;
   case 'checkbox':
    this.addEventListener("click", function() {
     console.log(this.type);
     sessionStorage.setItem(this.name, this.value);
     console.log("---- checkbox ----");
     console.log(this.value);
    });
    break;
   default :
   this.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
    console.log(this.type);
     sessionStorage.setItem(this.name, this.value);
     
     console.log("---- default ----");
    });
    break;
   }
});
```

Проблема с `checkbox` и `radio`, почему-то подменяется `value` (становится одинаковым) и не ставится `checked`.
Изначально:

```html
<div class="row-fluid">
 <div class="fabrikgrid_radio span1">
  <label class="fabrikgrid_0 radio">
   <input type="radio" class="fabrikinput " name="pdata_ch___gender[]" value="0">
   <span>М</span>
  </label>
 </div>
 <div class="fabrikgrid_radio span1">
  <label class="fabrikgrid_1 radio">
   <input type="radio" class="fabrikinput " name="pdata_ch___gender[]" value="1">
   <span>Ж</span>
  </label>
 </div>
</div>
```

После обновления страницы:

```html
<div class="row-fluid">
 <div class="fabrikgrid_radio span1">
  <label class="fabrikgrid_0 radio">
   <input type="radio" class="fabrikinput " name="pdata_ch___gender[]" value="0">
   <span>М</span>
  </label>
 </div>
 <div class="fabrikgrid_radio span1">
  <label class="fabrikgrid_1 radio">
   <input type="radio" class="fabrikinput " name="pdata_ch___gender[]" value="0">
   <span>Ж</span>
  </label>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил таким способом:

```js
if (sessionStorage.getItem(this.name) && this.type != 'radio' && this.type != 'checkbox') {
  this.value = sessionStorage.getItem(this.name);
}else if(sessionStorage.getItem(this.name) && (this.type == 'radio' || this.type == 'checkbox')){

   var ses_name = this.name;
   var ses_val = sessionStorage.getItem(this.name);
    $('[name="'+ ses_name +'"][value="'+ ses_val +'"]').attr('checked','checked');
}
```

Осталась проблема с зависимыми селектами, которые поочередно загружаются из БД.